# res.send vs res.locals in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
app.get('/p/:tagId', function(req, res) {
  res.send("tagId is set to " + req.param("tagId"));
});
```

What does res.send do above? If I want to get the tagId value I can do

```
res.locals.tagId = resq.param("tagId");
```

What's the different?

Comment: Are you asking about the difference between `res` and `resq`?

Comment: no. res.send vs res.locals. My question make sense?

Comment: No, [it](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.locals) [doesn't](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.send). They're clearly different.

Comment: @Bergi so is it a preferences thingy if i just want to send a var value from controller to view? what's the point of using res.send to do that? I just need the value.

Comment: What do you mean by "view"? No, `res.send` does directly send a response to the client. Setting `res.locals.…` only makes the value accessible to renderers later in your chain (which will then call  `res.send`).

Comment: @bergi oh really? so what's the different btw res.locals and res.send? I'm more confused now.

Answer (score 1):

```
res.send
```

sends a HTTP response when a user loads the page, whereas

```
res.locals
```

creates a local variable scoped to this request, meaning to say you can use res.locals.tagId anywhere in this request.

And finally, it is

```
req.param.tagId
```

not

```
req.param("tagId")
```

Comment: so res.send is actually quite dangerous, do 50 res.send and u will have conflict.

Comment: res.send sends an entire HTTP response to the client, including headers and content, so no, you won't be able to send it 50 times. but you can do res.write('test') 50 times if you like.

Comment: @user3519144: That sounds like "computers are quite dangerous".